# How to resave a csv file using pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have read a csv file using Pandas and I need to resave the csv file using code instead of opening the csv file and manually saving it.

Is it possible?

Comment: If your data frame is the variable `df`, use `df.to_csv('path/to/file.csv')`

Answer (score 2):

There must be something I'm missing in the question. Why not simply:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', ...)

# any changes

df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

?